# VueJs Lost Prop Data After Restart Page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, parent-child, vue-props

**Hi friends,**

**I am passing data from parent component to child component. But the data I send to the child component sometimes shows " "(empty text) in the console. For example, when I refresh the page with Ctrl+F5. How can I pass my data to the child component without losing it? Can you help me? My goal is to move route information from parent component to child component.**

**Thanks for your helps.**

**Child Component Codes**

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ["currentRoute"],
    methods: {
        _checkRoutes() {
                console.log("Child Component:: ", this.currentRoute);
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this._checkRoutes();
    }
}
</script>
```

**Parent Component ScreenShots**

[Parent Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IHlw.png)
[Parent Component set Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5S2y.png)

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4kEH.png)

[Page Route is "/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vB9Z.png)

Comment: child mounted() methods run before parent mounted() methods.  you haven't lost the currentRoute, it's just not yet available at the time you console log.  try viewing live debugging data with [vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/), you should see the route is passed down just fine every time.  also in the future please include code snippets in your question instead of screenshots when possible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments section, you are not losing data. It is just that your data (in your case the prop) is not reactive, meaning by the time prop is updated, `ChildComponent.vue` mounted was already called.

If you want to be able to work with a data passed throughout a prop, you can either `watch` ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example)) for that prop, or simply define a `computed` ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example)) that will depend on that specific prop.

So, in your case, it should be something like this:

```js
export default {
    props: ["currentRoute"],
    methods: {
        _checkRoutes() {
                console.log("Child Component:: ", this.currentRoute);
        }
    },
    watch:{
        currentRoute: () {
            this._checkRoutes()
        }
    }
}
```

`computed` example:

```js
export default {
    props: ["currentRoute"],
    computed:{
        currentWindowRoute: () {
            // Do some checks, call a method or whatever
            // and return something (value, Boolean, whatever you need for the case)
            return this.currentRoute;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `computed` approach usually requires a return value.